# jquery 1.8.3 and onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick, checkbox

I'm using jquery to check and uncheck items in order to associate actions to them. Very common task... The functions below work great for that. The problem appears after using an ajax load() to refresh the list, in that case the onclick events don't respnd anymore:

1) Jquery functions

```
$('#checkItemsAll').change(function() { 
        var cb = $("#filesSection").find(':checkbox');
        if(this.checked) {
            cb.attr('checked', true); 
            cb.each(function(o){
                var chkID = $(this).val();
                $("#"+chkID).addClass('alert alert-info');
              });
        }else{ 
            cb.attr('checked', false);
            cb.each(function(o){
                var chkID = $(this).val();
                $("#"+chkID).removeClass('alert alert-info');
              });
        }
    });

    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
          $('#'+this.value).addClass('alert alert-info');
        }
      else {
          $('#'+this.value).removeClass('alert alert-info');
      }
    });
```

2) the load function  call, has refreshed the list but checkboxes click events don't respond on the new list (the js in still attached to the new list by the way)

```
$("#filesSection").load(node.data.url+'?folderId='+node.data.key);
```

have you met this before ? A solution i'm investigating now is on add an onclick event on the checkbox input , but i suppose there is a way to manage the onclick.

Cheers

LL

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Kevin B said. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:checkbox', function(){
...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, event delegation propagates and rocks!